# Dockerizing legacy Spring war project using startup.sh instead of catalina.sh

Tags: spring, docker, tomcat, war

I currently have to containerize a legacy Spring war project that uses Apache Tomcat server.

On my local machine I do not run into any trouble running with the following configurations
[image]

On the actual server it the server seems to use startup.sh instead of catalina.sh to start the server as can be seen in the shell script below

```bash
export CATALINA_OPTS="-Denv=product -Denv.servername=instance3 -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Dspring.profiles.active=prod"
cd $CATALINA_HOME/bin
./startup.sh
#./catalina.sh run
```

I have tried building a dockerfile cotaing the information from the shell script as below.

```
FROM tomcat:9.0.40
EXPOSE 8083
COPY ./build/libs/ROOT.war "$CATALINA_HOME"/webapps/ROOT.war
ENV JAVA_OPTS='-Dspring.profiles.active=local'
RUN chmod +x $CATALINA_HOME/bin/startup.sh
RUN cd $CATALINA_HOME/bin
RUN /startup.sh
```

However I run into an error stating that /startup.sh was not found.

```
 => CACHED [2/5] COPY ./build/libs/ROOT.war /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/ROOT.war                                                                                                                                                                                             0.0s
 => [3/5] RUN chmod +x /usr/local/tomcat/bin/startup.sh                                                                                                                                                                                                                    0.3s
 => [4/5] RUN cd /usr/local/tomcat/bin                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     0.3s
 => ERROR [5/5] RUN /startup.sh                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            0.2s
------
 > [5/5] RUN /startup.sh:
#9 0.162 /bin/sh: 1: /startup.sh: not found
```

This is my first time using a war file so I am a bit unfamiliar with what I am doing, so any type of feedback would be deeply appreciated.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: /startup.sh addresses the root folder. Remove the initial / or use ./startup.sh

Comment: You probably also want this to be `CMD` and not `RUN`.  Using the absolute path `CMD "$CATALINA_HOME/bin/startup.sh"` might be clearest (`RUN cd` does nothing).